# jquery selector finding div without id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="target">
    <div>here</div>
    <div>select this<div>it has more div within</div></div>
<div></div>
```

How to get the last child of target? I tried

`$('#target').find('div:nth-child(2)')`

Is this even correct? It seems like it will also select div within my target, which is what I don't want, hmm.

Comment: @prasad Most of the answers there assume there are no deeply nested elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#target').children().last();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-class selector with [direct child selector(`>`)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

```
$('#target > div:last-child')
```

```js
console.log($('#target>div:last-child').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <div>here</div>
  <div>select this
    <div>it has more div within</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To select the second child use [`:nth-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) along with [direct child selector(`>`)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to avoid nested element.

```
$('#target > div:nth-child(2)')
```

```js
console.log($('#target > div:nth-child(2)').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <div>here</div>
  <div>select this
    <div>it has more div within</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me fix your markup first:

```
<div id="target">
    <div>here</div>
    <div>select this
        <div>it has more div within</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As far as I understood, you only want to select the text "select this". I am not sure what you are trying to do, but if you only want to get the text. You can just manipulate the string getting it using `text()` and then remove the `<div>...</div>` part. But, if you are trying to put some css attribute like color onto this node. You need to fix your div because of the cascading feature.

So instead, you might want to do this:

```
<div id="target">
    <div>here</div>
    <div>
        <div>select this</div>
        <div>it has more div within</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then

```
$("#target").children().last().children().first();
```